# Exception when running a rails application that uses the patron gem on jruby/osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use patron in my rails application when I run the server I get the following exception however when I run rails console I do not get any exception and I am even able to use methods in my Ruby class that use Patron. Any idea what the issue may be?

```
/Users/<user>/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.2/bin/jruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/<user>/rails/share-app/web/share-ui/script/rails server mongrel -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
LoadError: load error: patron/session_ext -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/patron-0.4.16/lib/patron/session_ext.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/patron-0.4.16/lib/patron/session_ext.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/polyglot-0.3.2/lib/polyglot.rb:63
   (root) at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/patron-0.4.16/lib/patron/session.rb:30
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/polyglot-0.3.2/lib/polyglot.rb:63
   (root) at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/patron-0.4.16/lib/patron/session.rb:30
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/patron-0.4.16/lib/patron.rb:68
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
  require at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120
   (root) at /Users/<user>/rails/share-app/web/share-ui/config/application.rb:19
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/<user>/rails/share-app/web/share-ui/config/application.rb:28
      tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1770
   (root) at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:6
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063
   (root) at -e:1
```

Comment: Did you get a fix. I am also facing issues with `patron` on `jruby 1.6.2`

Comment: I didn't really get around to this but this seems to obviously be something to do with environment. Since it complains that it found the dynamic link library but the architecture was wrong one thing you could try is setting the ARCHFLAGS to something appropriate and see if that helps.

Comment: I got it.. :) Its a ruby dependency patron is not compatible with jRuby.